# Stick one figure under another

Tags: graphics

I want to fill a page with two figures (one under the other). In other words, I don't want any text in between.

I tried to do it several ways, (but I don't think it's the correct one). I first tried to add `\pagebreak` to avoid text in between the figures; but this is a very crappy solution if you then add text above, since it changes the text arrangement.

The other thing I tried is the following:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subcaptionbox{Equilibrium points.\label{fig:equi}}{%
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./setup/DryAsphalt/EquilibriumBasic}%
  }\par\medskip
\subcaptionbox{Equilibrium points (with iterations).\label{fig:equi2}}{%
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./setup/DryAsphalt/Equilibrium}%
  }\par\medskip 
  \caption{Equilibrium points in MSD control (dry asphalt)} 
  \label{fig:Equilibria}      
\end{figure}
```

However, what I obtain are two subfigures (for example Fig. 3.1.a and Fig 3.1.b). And I need two independent figures.

What would be the correct way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see if the folowing mwe gives what you like to have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htp]
    \centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=0.45\textheight]{./setup/DryAsphalt/EquilibriumBasic}
    \caption{Equilibrium points}
\label{fig:equi}

\bigskip
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=0.45\textheight]{./setup/DryAsphalt/Equilibrium}
    \caption{Equilibrium points in MSD control (dry asphalt)}
\label{fig:Equilibria}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, it works exactly how I wanted. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another answer with capt-of and tabu package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[ht]
        \centering
        \begin{tabu}to \textwidth {X[c]}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}\captionof{figure}{\label{Fig:Top}Top Figure}  \\
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}\captionof{figure}{\label{Fig:Bottom}Bottom Figure}  \\
        \end{tabu}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: figures]